# How does this syntax come true in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
        'pics': {
        ';c:black;': 'xxx1.jpg',
        ';c:red;': 'xxx2.jpg',
        ';c:gary;': 'xxx3.jpg',
        ';c:blue;': 'xxx2.jpg',
    },
```

smarty template code :

```
{{if pics[';' + index + ':' + sid + ';']}}
   // Do something..
```

**index** and **sid** are derived from another set of dict.

How does this syntax come true in Django template?

Because I'm a novice, I need an demo , Hope to help me thank you！！

Comment: It doesn't. You can't do this in a Django template. (And I can't really see why you'd want to.)